# Angular Typed Forms & Validators | Case Example

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder, angular-custom-validators

Let's assume having a simple form like this:

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
   myNumber: this.formBuilder.control<number | null>(
      null,
      Validators.required
   )
});
```

The control `myNumber` is typed as `number | null` as no default value should be shown within the UI. The component should render an empty `input` of type `number`.

Let's assume that the corresponding form can be submitted and that the submission is handled like this:

```
protected onSubmit(): void {
   if (this.form.invalid) return;
   
   const formValue = this.form.getRawValue();
   
   // Further logic using the valid form value
}
```

The function `onSubmit` does an early return having an invalid form. If the form is valid further logic is executed; e.g. saving/persisting the entered number.

The type of `formValue.myNumber` is still `number | null`, even though it can't be `null` due to the usage of `Validators.required` and the check using `this.form.invalid`.

This means that an additional check has to be done if the entered number should be provided as a payload for some kind of service.

This means that we have to do something like this:

```
if (typeof formValue.myNumber == "number") {
   // Use formatValue.myNumber as a payload
}
```

And this is annoying. Why should the same check be done that the validator ensures anyway?

How do you guy's deal with this problem?

In my opinion it would be cool if a validator narrows down the type of the control. E.g. that `Validators.required` acts as a type guard and excludes `null` as a possible type having a valid form. But as far as I know this is not possible right now, or am I wrong?

I would be really interested how the Angular community deals with this scenario in general. Any thought appreciated.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wqjd4q?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Greets Lukas

Comment: You can write `myNumber: this.formBuilder.control<number>(NaN, Validators.required)`. Then you don't have to check for the *number* type.

Comment: I guess that’s right, but let‘s assume that it is not about a number but rather about an object named address. What would you do then?

Comment: `HTMLInputElement` doesn't support typing in objects. So in that case, you build form groups and use individual fields for individual controls (i.e. Address Line 1, Address Line 2, City, State, Zip - total 5 input fields).

Comment: I know, of course, but in this case one would use a custom `ControlValueAccessor`.